# Stop line by line javascript animation from looping

Tags: javascript

I'm currently working with a piece of javascript which fades in a paragraph of text line by line.

Javascript isn't by forte and I'm struggling to stop the animation from looping.

Any help and advice on how to achieve this would be great.
Here is a link to a fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/spittman/7wpqkfhj/5

Thanks!

Javascript

```
$(document).ready(function() {


function fadeInLine(line){
  $('<span />', {
    html: line.trim(),
    style: "opacity: 0"
  })
  .appendTo($greeting)
  .animate({opacity:1}, 500);
}

function rotateLines(interval){
  setTimeout(() => {
    if(i >= lines.length-1){
      i = 0;
      interval = 1500;
      setTimeout(()=>{ $greeting.empty(); }, interval)
    } else {
      fadeInLine(lines[i]);
      i++;
      interval = 1500;
    }
    rotateLines(interval);
  }, interval);
}

const $greeting = $('div#container p');
const text = $greeting.html();
const lines = text.split("\n").filter((e) => e.replace(/\s+/, ""));
let i = 0;

$greeting.empty();
rotateLines();



});
```

Html

```
<div id="container">
  <p>
    There’s another side to London.<br>
    Beyond the jurisdiction of The City.<br>
    Undiscovered by outsiders.<br>
    Loved by insiders.<br>
    An ever-changing place...<br>
    That teases our wildside and thrills our artside.<br>
    Blurs our workside into our playside.<br>
    Where we live on the brightside.<br>
    And explore our darkside.<br>
    Hidden in plain sight, this is Bankside.<br>
    London’s other side.<br>
    .
  </p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put the scheduled call in the `else` clause, and delete the `greeting.empty()` line.

```
function rotateLines(interval){
  setTimeout(() => {
    if(i >= lines.length-1){
      i = 0;
      interval = 1500;
      // setTimeout(()=>{ $greeting.empty(); }, interval)
    } else {
      fadeInLine(lines[i]);
      i++;
      interval = 1500;
      rotateLines(interval);
    }
    // rotateLines(interval); 
  }, interval);
}
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/e786kpyb/1/)

The animation stops after the whole text has faded in.

Answer (score 0):

Simply get rid of the if-clause that resets the element and counter.

```
function rotateLines(interval){
  setTimeout(() => {
      fadeInLine(lines[i]);
      i++;
      interval = 1500;

    rotateLines(interval);
  }, interval);
}
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/7wpqkfhj/19/)

Comment: What happens when `i` exceeds the boundary of `lines`? I got `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'trim' of undefined
    at fadeInLine ((index):35)
    at setTimeout ((index):44)` in the console. YMMV.

Comment: You're right @meowgoesthedog I didn't even take into consideration that I wasn't working with a for-loop.